# JavaScript - Merge Object Array Every nth Element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of varying length containing objects in which each group of 4 corresponds to one element of interest (unfortunately this array cannot be changed)

Obviously there is a lot of duplicate data except for the description, correctiveAction etc.

```
[
 {
   ids: ['123', '124'],
   referenceNumbers: [],
   description: '',
 },
 {
   ids: ['123', '124'],
   referenceNumbers: [],
   correctiveAction: '',
 },
{
   ids: ['123', '124'],
   referenceNumbers: [],
   correctedBy: '',
 },
{
   ids: ['123', '124'],
   referenceNumbers: [],
   description: '',
   correctedDate:
 },
 ...

]
```

I am looking for a more elegant and efficient method of merging each group of 4 elements in this array, without duplicating the common fields.

This is my current solution, which works in the exact way I need it to, albeit inefficient:

```
const handleMergeDef = (defArr) => {
    let tempArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < defArr.length; i++) {
      tempArr.push({
        ids: defArr[i].ids,
        referenceNumbers: defArr[i].referenceNumbers,
        description: defArr[i].description,
        correctiveAction: defArr[i+1].correctiveAction,
        correctedBy: defArr[i+2].correctedBy,
        correctedDate: defArr[i+3].correctedDate
      })
      i+=3
    }
    return tempArr
  }
```

Expected Output:

```
[
 {
   ids: ['123', '124'],
   referenceNumbers: [],
   description: '',
   correctiveAction: '',
   correctedBy: '',
   correctedDate: ''
 },
 {
   ids: ['456', '457'],
   referenceNumbers: [],
   description: '',
   correctiveAction: '',
   correctedBy: '',
   correctedDate: ''
 },
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the input reliably appears in sequential quartets, your solution is fine. The notion of seeking forward in the array for desired values is necessary. You could pursue a more complicated grouping method but it may just be unnecessary overhead for your case.

Depending on how much data you're dealing with, you could get some performance<sup>*</sup> lift by predefining your output array length and assigning objects by explicit index, rather than pushing/resizing the array each time.

```js
const reduce = (array) => {
  const n = array.length;
  const output = new Array(Math.ceil(n / 4));
  let i = 0;
  let x = 0;
  while (i < n) {
    output[x++] = {
      ids: array[i].ids,
      referenceNumbers: array[i].referenceNumbers,
      description: array[i].description,
      correctiveAction: array[i + 1].correctiveAction,
      correctedBy: array[i + 2].correctedBy,
      correctedDate: array[i + 3].correctedDate,
    };
    i += 4;
  };
  return output;
};

const input = [
  {
    ids: ['123', '124'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    description: '',
  },
  {
    ids: ['123', '124'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    correctiveAction: 'Terminate',
  },
  {
    ids: ['123', '124'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    correctedBy: 'Jane',
  },
  {
    ids: ['123', '124'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    description: '',
    correctedDate: "2022-10-31"
  },
  {
    ids: ['456', '457'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    description: '',
  },
  {
    ids: ['456', '457'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    correctiveAction: 'Promote',
  },
  {
    ids: ['456', '457'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    correctedBy: 'John',
  },
  {
    ids: ['456', '457'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    description: '',
    correctedDate: "2022-11-01"
  },  
  {
    ids: ['678', '689'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    description: '',
  },
  {
    ids: ['678', '689'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    correctiveAction: 'Transfer',
  },
  {
    ids: ['678', '689'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    correctedBy: 'Xander',
  },
  {
    ids: ['678', '689'],
    referenceNumbers: [],
    description: '',
    correctedDate: "2022-11-03"
  },   
];

const output = reduce(input);

console.log(output);

// minor translation for table display
console.table(output.map(o=>{
  o.ids = o.ids.join(",");
  o.referenceNumbers = o.referenceNumbers.join(",");
  return o;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block}</style><script>console.config({timeStamps:false,maximize:true})</script>
```

<sup>*</sup>Here's [a jsbench](https://jsbench.me/n0la1dbiee/1) which compares the performance of your implementation and those of these answers. This test generates an input array of 2,048 objects. Your mileage may vary based on your system load. Feel free to fork the test to try different setups.

Comment: The function will be handling well over 1,000 objects so the 12-14% increase in performance for sure makes a difference, well done!